# Error al querer eliminar una imagen en una carpeta en ASP.NET - VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

--- EDITADO

Ya corregi unas cosas y ahora me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error.. como si no tuviese permisos para acceder a dicha carpeta donde estan las imagenes:

**Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso**

```
File.Delete(MapPath(e.CommandArgument.ToString()))
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Estimados, estoy programando en ASP.NET VB por primera vez, estoy creando en estos momentos un sistema que me permita cargar y eliminar imagenes en una carpeta determinada, la carga funciona, pero al querer eliminar me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error: **No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.EventArgs' al tipo 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs'.**

Error de codigo fuente:

```
Width="156px" BorderWidth="2px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("path") %>' />
<br />
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Command" 
Text='<%# Eval("path") %>' oncommand="LinkButton1_Command"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

El error lo marca en la linea que esta despues del 
.

Elimino la imagen con el siguiente codigo:

```
Protected Sub LinkButton1_Command(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs)
        File.Delete(MapPath(e.CommandArgument.ToString()))
        Response.Write("Imagen eliminada satisfactoriamente")
    End Sub
```

Comment: a simple vista, estas usando el mismo evento para dos cosas distintas en tu control. Parece un error de tipografia.

Comment: Ya corregi unas cosas y ahora me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error.. como si no tuviese permisos para acceder a dicha carpeta donde estan las imagenes.. Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso.... File.Delete(MapPath(e.CommandArgument.ToString()))

Comment: por favor. actualiza la pregunta. Usa el boton [edit] para modificarla y poner tu problema real.

Comment: Ya lo hice.....

Comment: y tenes permisos para borrar en esa carpeta?

Comment: No se como ver eso :/

Comment: el usuario de ASP.net que estas usando debe tener permisos de escritura sobre la carpeta. es muy probable (como te indica el error) que por eso falle.

Comment: en general, uno no da permisos de borrado a una aplicacion web.

Comment: Ya le di los permisos, me deja eliminar, lo raro que siempre que ejecuto automaticamente se me elimina sola una imagen